# why my ListViewItem can't be edit in c# class ListView

Tags: c#, listview

I've tried to find answers on MSDN but failed.

here is my code:

```
        ListView listView1 = new ListView();
        listView1.Bounds = new Rectangle(new Point(10, 10), new Size(300, 200));

        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.LabelEdit = true; //set here
        listView1.AllowColumnReorder = true;
        listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.GridLines = true; // show as grid
        listView1.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
```

this could only allow me to edit the first column of the list view. because only the first column is the label of each list view item.

what i want to do is edit every gird(list view item). any good suggestion?

Comment: I don't understand... having characters where? on the list view columns? on a list view item?

Comment: If it is true then you can edit an existing item... can you explain what are you trying to do in general?

Comment: When you create ListView, bind an item containing empty string, this might acheive what you want.

Comment: what i want to do is editing words in grid.actually, i want to find a control like a table,but i could only find listview.

Comment: @Furqan i changed the last two sentences of my question, now it is clearer.

Comment: IMHO, what ou are trying to acheive is not possible with list view, rather you should go for GridView or some other third party control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
ListView listView1 = new ListView();
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.LabelEdit = true;
listView1.Columns.Add("Item Column", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Columns.Add("Column 2", -2, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]{"",""});
listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[]{"",""});
.
. (how many items you want to edit)
```

Comment: i just find the truth that i could use `datagirdview` to fix the problem, thanks all the same.